# WPF content in ElementHost not visible using DockPanel Suite

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I have a WPF control in an ElementHost on a WinForms form. I've added the Form to a DockPanel Suite pane. The WPF content displays correctly when the Form is floating, or docked left/right/top/bottom, but when DockState is Document the WPF content disappears, leaving a blank docked Form.

I've experimented with creating empty test WPF controls, and this behaviour occurs whenever an ElementHost is used on a WinForm, and docked using DPS. Can anyone suggest where to look for a fix ? I've set the WPF rendering to Software only, but it doesn't help with this problem.

Many thanks.

WinForms App using .NET 4.0, VS2012 on Windows 7 on VMWare Fusion on MacBook Pro.

Comment: This may be related to sizes. winforms doesn't support resolution independence so you have to size stuff manually. Make sure the WPF content and the ElementHost itself is sized properly.

Comment: Right, now fixed. The problem wan't the sizing, or even the WPF, although checking up on how the control was being sized put me on the right track.

Comment: If you found a solution for your problem, please post it as an answer here for future references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much poking around, the problem turned out to be due to a ToolStripContainer that was on the same form as the DPS DockPanel. When the ElementHost form was docked as document, this was being rendered over the top of it. I replaced the ToolStripContainer with a separate ToolStrip and MenuStrip (following the DockSample), and all works fine.